# checking if a array is alpha

Tags: c, cs50

I need to check if there is first a key entered in the comand line (which i have done and works). I then need to check that the key entered is not alphabetical.

I have managed to make it so that if a aplha key was entered it will display the warning, however if the key is entered for example as 2THG.  It still works using the number as opposed to showing the warning.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main (int argc , string argv[])
{
    if (argc != 2 )
    {
        printf ("Usage: ./caesar key\n");
        return 1;
    }
    if (isalpha (*argv [1]))
    {
        printf ("usage: ./caesar key\n");
        return 1;
    }
```

Comment: `*argv[1]` is the same as `argv[1][0]`. That is you only check if the *first* character is alphabetic, not the whole string.

Comment: Assuming the key must be a number, it would be better to check if **all** characters are numeric instead of "not alphabetic". To check for a valid number you could also use the conversion function `strtol` and check the output parameter that points to the first invalid character (`*endptr` or `*str_end`). See the documentation of `strtol`: https://linux.die.net/man/3/strtol, https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtol. BTW: instead of displaying the same "usage" message, the error message should show that `key` must be numeric (or similar).

Answer (score 0):

call to "isalpha (*argv [1])" checks only the first char. If we need to check te string each char of the string needs to be passed to isalpha separately.

Sample code:

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <ctype.h>
    #include <string.h>

    int main (int argc , char* argv[]) {
        int i = 0;
        if (argc != 2 ) {
            printf ("Usage: ./caesar key -1\n");
            return 1;
        }

        for (i = 0; i < strlen(argv[1]); i++) {
            if (isalpha(argv[1][i])) {
                printf ("usage: ./caesar key\n");
                return 1;
            }
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Please use a consistent bracket style.

Comment: The [`isalpha`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/isalpha) function is not guaranteed to return a strict boolean result. It could return any non-zero value for alphabetical characters.

Comment: If needing to verify each character in string  `argv[1]` is _numeric_ only, then `isdigit(argv[1][i])`, for all `i` in a loop can be used.

Answer (score 0):

This expression:

```
*argv [1]
```

Checks only the first character of the array `argv[1]`.  To test all characters, loop thorough using one of the following equivalent expressions:

```
argv[1][i]
```

or:

```
*(argv[1] + i)
```

Also, there is a similar function used to test for numeric character values:  [int isdigit(int c)](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_isdigit.htm).  It is illustrated below in a loop to verify content of `argv[1]`:

```
int len = strlen(argv[1]);

for(int i=0;i<len;i++)
{
     if(!isdigit(argv[1][i]))//leave upon first non-numeric character
     {
          printf ("usage: ./caesar key\n");
          return 1;
     }
}
```